# How to display link to FB page I admin on my FB profile?

Tags: facebook

How do I display link to FB page I admin on my FB profile? Example in picture.

[image: Links for pages]

Comment: Have you been able to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

If you remember your page's unique username (PAGE_ID):

1. go to `https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?PAGE_ID&sk=featured`
2. click **Edit Featured Page Owners**
3. select yourself
4. click **Save**

If you don't remember the unique username:

1. go to your page
2. click **Edit Page**
3. go to **Featured** section (link's 5th from the top on the left)
4. follow steps 2-4 from above